# Ejecutar Procedimiento almacenado con parámetros obtenidos de una consulta SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, tsql, transact-sql

tengo una consulta que obtiene los id de los registros que necesito hacer un insert como clave foranea,
el insert lo realizo a traves de un stored procedure.

Generalmente el insertlo realizo individualmente, pero por una falla de sistema, ahora necesito insertar muchos (miles) de registros a la vez

La Consulta es asi, obtiene como unica columna los id que necesito actualizar/insertar:

```
SELECT i.id 
FROM informes 
 WHERE (YEAR(Fecha ) =2022 AND MONTH(fecha)=6 AND DAY (Fecha)=6) AND 
       t.IdServicio IN(75,76,77,68,129)
       AND DeterminacionNombre ='url'
       AND ValorTexto IS NOT NULL
```

El procedimiento almacenado solo recibe un parametro, un id. serian cada uno de los obtenidos en la consulta mencionada arriba.

Ejemplo

```
sp_informes_addEnlace  100578
```

como podria ejecutar ese procedimiento, tantas veces como filas resulten de la consulta ?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: probablemente lo más simple sería usar un cursor

Comment: No te es más conveniente editar el store y pasarle una tabla como dato?

Comment: Como sería eso @KevinBarrios?

Comment: Primero tienes que crear un "tipo de dato" que sea table, ejem: CREATE TYPE datos as table (id int), y en tu store creas una variable de entrada del tipo "datos" @tablatemp datos, así llenas la tabla y pasas los datos, revisa la documentación ya que mi ejemplo es muy basico.

Comment: Entendí muy poco,  aunque haya resuelto el tema voy a revisar la documentación `xq parece ser util, gracias de todos modos!

Answer (score 3):

Un cursor sería una forma simple de lograr esto:

```
DECLARE @id int;

DECLARE CC CURSOR FOR
SELECT i.id 
FROM informes 
WHERE Fecha = '20220606'
AND t.IdServicio IN (75,76,77,68,129)
AND DeterminacionNombre ='url'
AND ValorTexto IS NOT NULL
;

OPEN CC
FETCH NEXT FROM CC INTO @id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.sp_informes_addEnlace @id
    FETCH NEXT FROM CC INTO @id
END
CLOSE CC
DEALLOCATE CC
;
```

Comment: Obtengo "comandos compilados correctamente"  pero el procedimiento no se ejecuta ni una sola vez.

Comment: Ya pude hacerlo funcionar

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una estrategia muy fácil de implementar pero solo es útil para casos puntuales ya que la idea es crear una consulta que cree la consulta final.

```
SELECT 'EXEC dbo.sp_informes_addEnlace ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,i.id)
       FROM informes 
       WHERE (YEAR(Fecha ) =2022 AND MONTH(fecha)=6 AND DAY (Fecha)=6)       AND 
             t.IdServicio IN(75,76,77,68,129)
             AND DeterminacionNombre ='url'
             AND ValorTexto IS NOT NULL
```

El resultado se copia y pega en una nueva conexión y se ejecuta. Como te darás cuenta, es útil si esto lo tienes que hacer una sola vez y la cantidad de ejecuciones es medianamente razonable, si eventualmente es algo que va a ser repetitivo o la consulta arroja millones de filas, sin duda la respuesta de Lamak es la adecuada.

Comment: En una nueva conexion? es decir me crearia un texto con el nombre del sp y el parametro?

Comment: Básicamente lo que hace es construir las `n` llamadas al Sp, los resultados los copias y pegas en otro Query y lo ejecutas.

Comment: Si, entiendo. Es un poco engorroso hacerlo de esa manera, buscaba algo mas práctico, como la solución que me propuso Lamak